# openssl_csr_new don't work with PHP 5.4

Tags: php, openssl

Since I've upgraded to PHP 5.4.6 (from 5.3), when I try to use openssl_csr_new :

```
$dn = array(
    'localityName' => utf8_decode($localityName),
    'stateOrProvinceName' => utf8_decode($stateOrProvinceName),
    'countryName' => 'FR',
    'organizationName' => utf8_decode($organizationName),
    'commonName' => utf8_decode($commonName),
    'emailAddress' => utf8_decode($emailAddress),
);

$privkey = openssl_pkey_new(
    array(
        'private_key_bits' => 1024,
        'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
    )
);

$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey);
```

I get an error like this :

```
Warning: openssl_csr_new(): in /my_file.php on line 42
```

Not really easy to debug this since there is no message...

Somebody know a fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if I remove all the utf8_decode which were used to render correctly the accented letters, it solve the problem.

Down side, the accented letters are not render correctly now. I hope this will be fix in the future releases of PHP.